How to display a tooltip above a word when that word is clicked (like Duolingo) in Jetpack Compose
I am trying to add a feature to my Jetpack Compose app where, when a user clicks a word, a tooltip will appear above/below that word, similar to Duolingo:

So far, I have an AnnotatedString that is able to print a word when it is clicked. Here is how I generate that AnnotatedString, given an input string:
val input = // get some string input from user
val words = input.parseInput() // split a String into a list of words and spaces (e.g. "Hello world" -> ["Hello", " ", "world"])
data class AnnotatedWord(word: String,  tag: String)
val annotatedWords = emptyList<AnnotatedWord>()
var wordIndex = 0
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    words.forEach { word ->
        if (word == " ") {
            append(word)
            continue
        }
        val tag = "${word}:${wordIndex++}"
        pushStringAnnotation(tag = tag, annotation = tag)
        withStyle(style = SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline)) {
            append(word)
        }
        pop()
        annotatedWords.add(AnnotatedWord(word, tag))
    }
}

And here is how I display it, with a click listener:
ClickableText(
    text = annotatedString,
    onClick = { index ->
        val annotation = annotatedString.getStringAnnotations(start = index, end = index).firstOrNull()
        if (annotation != null) {
            val tag = annotation.tag
            val matchingWord = annotatedWords.find { it.tag == tag }
            print(matchingWord.word)
        }
    }
)

This works well - it gives me a string where each word is underlined, and clicking a word prints it. However I'm struggling with the tooltip part. I think I can display the Tooltip by nesting ClickableText in a Box, putting the tooltip inside that Box as well, and positioning it above the word using Modifier.offset(). However, I'm not sure how to get this offset, let alone how to pass it to my composable from the AnnotatedString.

on text put the onglobleposition property of the modifier and from that, you get the offset of your text create the custom tooltip, and put that offset.

Hi! Can you share how you solved it?

@Mamedov see the accepted answer

I ended up doing this:

Put both the Tooltip and Text in a Box
In Text.onTextLayout, get the offset like this:

// index = the index of the clicked character in the string
val wordBoundary = layoutResult.getWordBoundary(index)
val leftBox = layoutResult.getBoundingBox(wordBoundary.min)
val rightBox = layoutResult.getBoundingBox(wordBoundary.max - 1)
val middle = (leftBox.left + rightBox.right) / 2
val top = leftBox.top
val offset = Offset(x = middle, y = top)


In The Tooltip's Modifier.layout, position the tooltip like this:

val placeable = measurable.measure(constraints)
val width = placeable.width
val height = placeable.height
// set width/height to 0 so the tooltip doesn't take up any space in its container
layout(0, 0) {
    val x = (offset.x - (width / 2)).toInt()
    val y = (offset.y - height).toInt()
    placeable.placeRelative(x, y)
}

It ended up looking like this:

